# website showing blank page after deploy in react

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

I am very new at React and for the first time, I'm trying to deploy my website using Github pages.

I followed all the instructions and did exactly what needs to be done but the problem is that I see a blank page...

Can someone help me with this?

here's my repo: https://github.com/lidorb94/instagram-ui

Comment: The problem seems to be that the page is served on github as a project page, and your relative links are broken. Cf. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths on how to specifiy the base url for CRA

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to install the `gh-pages` npm package. You have to set a `homepage` in your `package.json` like `"homepage": "link-to-repo"`

Then add a script to your package like:

```
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
```

Your scripts should look something like

```
"scripts": {    
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "predeploy": "yarn run build",
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Comment: yes i did all of this and my repo looks like this. but i still don't manage to make it to work. it shows a blank page.

Comment: Did you do a build first?

Comment: what do you mean? i didn't run npm run build if thats what you mean

Comment: You need to run a build step first. That's what will be used when you deploy to gh pages

Answer (score 0):

`path='/'` in your router means you are literally matching `/` (e.g. `https://lidorb94.github.io/`), but in fact, your project is on `https://lidorb94.github.io/instagram-ui/`. Use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` as a basename prop on your `BrowserRouter` like so;

```
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  {/* routes */}
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: it says "Line 11:8:  'BrowserRouter' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef"

Comment: @LidorBatino you have to import them first `import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming u have added the following lines in your package.json file and did npm run build

```
"homepage":"https://{Your_Github_Username}.github.io/{repo-name}", //outside dependencies

"scripts": {
    .
    .
    "predeploy":"npm run build",
    "deploy":"gh-pages -d build"
}
```

If that doesn't work then check your console if you find any errors.

I was able to fix the issue after I saw the error in the console. In my case the error was with the https request. I had added a script link in index.html with 'http' when I changed it to 'https' it worked perfectly fine.

And don't forget to commit and push the changes after you have found the error and run deploy again...